# Chest excercises without bench

Tags: chest

I currently don't have access to a bench but I wan't to target my chest.

This question:

> [How should I do push up to get better chest?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3105/how-should-i-do-push-up-to-get-better-chest)

has some great info about targetting your chest with push ups.

I have an ez-curl bar and dumb bells. Are there any other exercises that I can do to really target my pectorals?

Comment: If you have a place to hang them, using rings are a great way to progress from push-ups using bodyweight only.

Comment: In addition to the other answers, you can look up "floor press". It's basically a bench press but, you guessed it, on the floor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an inexpensive [exercise ball](http://www.dickssportinggoods.com/products/exercise-balls.jsp), or, some other **stable** platform will increase the types of chest exercises that you can do.  For example, you would then be able to perform a dumbbell fly and a dumbbell pullover, as well as, dumbbell presses.

Otherwise, you can look into:

- Decline pushups with your feet on a stair.
- Incline pushups with your hands on a stair.

Answer (score 3):

Press ups, as stated in the question you linked to, are always a good option. You can use progressions and regressions, depending on your strength level.

Dumbbell floor presses are also a good alternative if you don't have a bench and you can probably do a dumbbell fly variation.

If you've got a couple of sturdy chairs, you can do dips between those (they target the chest if you lean forward slightly).

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion Dips will be the best to shred up your chest.

Often cited as the equivalent of the squat for the upper body.

I'm a big fan of the big compound moves where ever i can get them. They also have the added benefit of being able to be done pretty much anywhere, and there are dozens of variations  that you can do.

And you can add difficulty/extra resistance with a heavy backpack/weight vest/dip belt/resistance bands.